# MySQL JOINED table query should return zero but instead does not return those rows

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

```
SELECT sg.date, sg.groupName, sg.highlights, 
        user.display_name as displayName,
        COUNT(uc.groupName) as cmtcnt
FROM `saved_groups` as sg
    LEFT JOIN `user` on user.email = sg.userName
    LEFT JOIN `user_comments` as uc on sg.groupName = uc.groupName
WHERE uc.deleted=0
GROUP BY sg.groupName
```

I have two tables, `saved_groups` and `user_comments` and the second line of the query should (does, it works) return an extra column with the number of comments associated with each group.

However, when a group has zero comments associated with it, that group is simply not returned. The only rows returned are those that have `> 0` comments. Desired behavior is for all groupNames to be returned, and specify 0 for those rows that have zero associated comments in the uc table.

How can I fix this query?

I tried: `IF(uc.deleted=1, 0, COUNT(uc.groupName)) as cmtcnt` -- but that makes no difference, the same results are returned.

At this point, I'm unsure what next to try.

Suggestions?

#### Update:

Tried this:

```
SELECT sg.date, sg.groupName, sg.highlights, 
        user.display_name as displayName,
        COUNT(uc.groupName) as cmtcnt
FROM geom.saved_groups as sg
    JOIN geom.user on user.email = sg.userName
    JOIN geom.user_comments as uc on sg.groupName = uc.groupName
WHERE isnull(uc.deleted,0) in (0,1)
GROUP BY sg.groupName
```

Got:
`#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'isnull'`

Comment: Move the condition `uc.deleted=0` in the ON clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all records? Then remove the `WHERE` clause. You want `0` for the records with no count? Use `COALESCE`. Like this:

```
SELECT sg.date
, sg.groupName
, sg.highlights
, user.display_name as displayName
, COALESCE(COUNT(uc.groupName), 0) as cmtcnt 
FROM `saved_groups` as sg 
LEFT JOIN `user` on user.email = sg.userName 
LEFT JOIN `user_comments` as uc on sg.groupName = uc.groupName 
AND uc.deleted = 0 -- to get only comments that have not been deleted, and not the deleted ones
GROUP BY sg.groupName
```

Comment: Ha! That worked. I actually tried `COALESCE` but did it in combination with the WHERE clause, and I didn't think it was even worth mentioning because it seemed to make no difference *(due to the WHERE clause, I now know)*. You gave me the missing information. Many thanks.

Comment: `COUNT(uc.groupName)` never returns null, so COALESCE() is useless. What makes the difference in the ON clause.

Comment: @forpas I wasn't too sure about mysql and coalesce (mysql has/had unexpected behaviour sometimes (for me, anyway)), so added it to be sure.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Sorry, I must have implemented incorrectly - tried it again to update my feedback and it worked as advertised.  Many thanks for updating your answer to cover the AND condition - works great.

Answer (score 0):

Your where condition is filtering the records and making only those records to return which have data in `uc` hence no benefit of left join. You can do
(`uc.deleted=0 or uc.deleted is null)`
or
Move the condition uc.deleted with on condition with join

Comment: I don't understand how to implement your suggestion - how exactly would I adjust my query? (Example code, pls)  I've been attempting to test this but cannot get the syntax correct.

Answer (score -1):

check if uc.deleted=0 and remove the where condition.  the and handles the non null condition of the left join

```
SELECT sg.date, sg.groupName, sg.highlights, 
        user.display_name as displayName,
        COUNT(uc.groupName) as cmtcnt
FROM dbo.saved_groups as sg
    JOIN dbo.user on user.email = sg.userName
    LEFT JOIN dbo.user_comments as uc on sg.groupName = uc.groupName
    AND uc.deleted = 0
GROUP BY sg.groupName
```